# Named Queries not working in bonsai (does not return matched_queries)

Tags: elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I cant seem to get the `"_name"` parameter to work in my query, when I run it on a Bonsai hosted elasticsearch(same happened on a Searchly service). Did anyone have the same problem?

This exact query works in my local elasticsearch, it returns the "matched_queries" with "test" inside. But as soon as I switch the URL to the hosted service, it does not:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "hamburguer",
        "_name": "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What response do you get instead? I just tried on my searchly endpoint and it worked.

Comment: I just get the hits without the "matched_queries" inside. Im using the service as a heroku addon, could that be interfering somehow?

Comment: Some more information would help here. For example, your index settings and mappings, and a sample document that you're expecting the query to match.